# Spring boot requestcontextholder with completableFuture.supplyAsync

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future, requestcontext

I am developing an Api using spring boot. I need to call a dependent service asynchronously.
I have an interceptor which uses RequestContextHolder from spring to get the httpservletrequest. But as the  calls to dependent service is happening ashnchronously, a new thread is created for executing the dependent call and requestContextHolder.getAttributes returns null for the requests started in new thread. Any suggestions to overcome this?

Code :

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsyn(()-> dependentService.getSomething());
```

Interceptor:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (ServletRequest) (RequestContextHolder.getAttributes()).getRequest();
```

Here RequestContextHolder.getAttributes() returns null for the requests happening in new threads.Anyway to hold the requestcontext ?